# Expected number of elements does not match

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function

I am having an issue with the following code on a BMI data set with dimensions (500,4). The issue I am getting can be seen below the code.

'''

```
def detailed_analysis(data, pred = None):
    obs = data.shape[0]
    types = data.dtypes
    counts = data.apply(lambda x: x.count())
    uniques = data.apply(lambda x: [x.unique])
    nulls = data.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum())
    distincts = data.apply(lambda x: x.unique().shape[0])
    missing_ratio = (nulls / obs)*100
    skewness = data.skew()
    kurtosis = data.kurt()
    print('Data shape:', data.shape)

    if pred is None:
        cols = ['types', 'counts', 'nulls', 'distincts', 'missing_ratio', 'uniques', 'skewness', 'kurtosis']
        details = pd.concat([types, counts, nulls, distincts, missing_ratio, uniques, skewness, kurtosis], axis=1)
    else:
        corr = BMI_df.corr()[pred]
        details = pd.concat([types, counts, nulls, distincts, missing_ratio, uniques, skewness, kurtosis, corr], axis=1
                            , sort=False)
        corr_col = 'corr' + pred
        cols = ['types', 'counts', 'nulls', 'distincts', 'missing_ratio', 'uniques', 'skewness', 'kurtosis', corr_col]

    details.columns = cols
    dtypes = details.types.value_counts()
    print('____________________________\nData types:\n', dtypes)
    print('____________________________')
    return details

details = detailed_analysis(BMI_df, 'Weight')
display(details.sort_values(by='corr Weight', ascending=False))
```

'''

Error:

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 12 elements, new values have 9 elements

'''

```
   Gender  Height  Weight  Index
0    Male     174      96      4
1    Male     189      87      2
2  Female     185     110      4
3  Female     195     104      3
4    Male     149      61      3
Data shape: (500, 4)
```

'''

Comment: Can you provide an example of your DataFrame?

Comment: The DataFrame Contains columns: Index, Weight, Gender, Age, and Categorical Integer. There are a total of 500 datapoints.

Comment: Found it on Kaggle :D

Comment: You can give a snippet, first 5 rows. You can get it by using `df.head()`

Comment: '''   Gender  Height  Weight  Index
0    Male     174      96      4
1    Male     189      87      2
2  Female     185     110      4
3  Female     195     104      3
4    Male     149      61      3
Data shape: (500, 4)

Comment: I added snip to code above